# Whats wrong in my code! I want to print Fibonacci Series with values less than 4000000

Tags: c++, loops, fibonacci

I think I there is some problem in implementation of my loop!
Here's my code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i=2;
    long long int FiboNo[100];
    FiboNo[0] = 1;
    FiboNo[1] = 2;
    do{
        FiboNo[i]=FiboNo[(i-1)]+FiboNo[(i-2)];
        cout<<FiboNo[i]<<endl;
        i++;
    }while(FiboNo[i]<4000000);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is *not* a good question. Please do not encourage users to continue posting stuff like this by anwering their questions in the comments. We should not be doing debug-this-code-dump-for-me questions.

Comment: why do you need to store items in an array. You only need 3 variables

Comment: Francis, you made it work. But where I was wrong? In do while loops, I guess condition is tested after loop body.

Comment: you increment i before the test. that's the issue

Comment: @UmNyobe : you're right. I was correct about the solution, but i was not perfectly correct about the problem !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
do {
    FiboNo[i] = FiboNo[(i - 1)] + FiboNo[(i - 2)];
    cout << FiboNo[i] << endl;
    i++;
} while (FiboNo[i] < 4000000);
```

You are incrementing `i` before you compare.

```
do {
    FiboNo[i] = FiboNo[(i - 1)] + FiboNo[(i - 2)];
    cout << FiboNo[i] << endl;
} while (FiboNo[i++] < 4000000);
```

is what you want to do.

Here's what's happening:

```
i 2
fibo[2] is 2
now i is 3
fibo[3] is 0
```

This has no problem,  when `fibo[someIndex]` reaches the limit. It wont come out, because your value is always a `0`.